# Navigation between different pages of website on server

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, client-server

I'm facing problem in a simple website, where I'm using buttons to switch between different pages,
behind the every button I'm using `onclick()` method to open other page.
Method I'm using is `onclick = "windows.open('xyz.html')"` of JavaScript.
but when I do click on a button to open a specific page , that specific page does not open, another page become appear instead.

> Note: website is placed on server of apachi(wamp server) using php there.

Comment: So you think without looking at some demo or code we can help you out????

Comment: can u give link so that we can check,also check with window.location='xyz.html'

Comment: You want to open in `New window or New tab`?

Comment: i've 3 pages in web.   1- index(home page).html  2- signUp page.html  3- signUp-action.html          when i click on signup button second page appear and when i do click on submit 3rd will appear. but on 3rd page when i clicks on home button ,, home page does not appears..

Comment: but how to provide code here Richa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
window.location.href = 'xyz.html';

window.open('xyz.html')//This will open xyz.html in a new window.
```

Comment: windows.open or window.open

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.location='xyz.html'
```

Comment: mean problem is because of that function which i'm using there?

Comment: window.open will open the page in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
onclick="window.location='xyz.html' ";
```

OR

```
header("Location:http: //www.xyz.html/") ` (or) ` header('Location: http://www.xyz.html/');
```